# Dynamic Saving in actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, save, constants

I am relatively new to AS3. I have some data that are important to be saved constantly. I use SharedObject.getLocal command to save them. But as far as I know the changes in the data are applied whenever I close my program. It is important to assure they are saved, for instance, every five minutes to protect them against unexpected events like power cut. I would appreciate if you help me know if there is a way around.

Comment: Call the **flush()** method on your **SharedObject** instance every time you change anything or every five minutes. That forces the actual disk write operation.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was a great help

Comment: My friend, I tried the method you said, it works when I shut down my laptop normally. I tried to simulate a power cut by suddenly remove the charger cable, having removed the battery as well ,which to my surprise  not only it does not work, but all data are also lost. Indeed, the locally saved file also vanishes.

Comment: It's a **force majeure** circumstances. If user's PC is powered off improperly, or struck with lightning, or burned, or thrown into a river, or hit with an axe, or shot with 5.56 assault rifle — indeed, the application data might be lost, but the loss of **YOUR** application data would probably be the least of the user's problems.